# how does this work ? for loop strips variable result

Tags: bash, shell-script

while learning bash/ksh from a book. 
i came across an exercise that had a result i would love to understand.

When executing this script with bash -x to try to understand how it behaves (debugging) i noticed the line variable is number + filename. as this is the result of wc -c [file].
but as soon as the for loop sets the res variable it somehow strips the file name and only says res=23
(number result of wc -c) i can see it happening but don't really understand why ? i think i understand the for loop construct ..
for i in xxx do what ever.. don't 100% understand the break in this construct i do know it's to break out of a nested loop.

this is the exercise script:

```
if [ ! $# -eq 2 ] ;then
    echo
    echo "usage: $0 <location> <FileName>"
    echo
    exit 1
fi
TMPFILE=/tmp/count
line=$(find "$1" -name "$2" -type f -print | tee $TMPFILE | wc -l)
aant=$line
nr=0
som=0

while [ $nr -lt "$aant" ] ; do
    nr=$(( nr +1 ))
    bestand=$(head -$nr $TMPFILE | tail -1)
    echo -n "$bestand"
    line=$(wc -c "$bestand")

    for woord in $line ; do
        res=$woord
        break
    done
    echo "  $res"
    som=$(( som + res ))
done

if [ "$aant" -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "No files found"
else
    echo
    echo "In totaal $aant files take $som bytes of space"
fi

rm $TMPFILE
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the magic happens right here:

```
for woord in $line ; do
    res=$woord
    break
done
```

To help you understand how that works, maybe considering this will help:

```
for N in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo $N
done
echo "N is $N"
```

Next, add the "`break`" statement and consider:

```
for N in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo $N
    break
done
echo "N is $N"
```

Can you describe what adding the `break` statement did to the `for` loop?

In my opinion, the four lines of code I originally quoted could be pared down to just three:

```
for res in $line ; do
    break
done
```

This is essentially a "kludgy" way of saying:

```
res="$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$line")"
```

Comment: thanks appreciate your help... your little test was a big help to visualize what was happening.. without the break i got a print of each number in a new line 1 true 5.. and on the last line : N is 5. Adding the break i only got 1 and then N is 1. running it with bash -x showed this clearly.. more so then my script.. as i said to "ilkkachu" i did see the break when running it with bash -x .. but did not fully realize what was going on i guess. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In `for word in $line`, the contents of the variable `line` is [split to words](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and then expanded for filename globs (see also [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)). The loop then runs once for each resulting value (or "word"). In this case though, there is only one iteration of the loop at most, since the `break` statement stops the loop from running. As a result, the value of `res` set on that first iteration of the loop remains, and the effect is the same as picking the first whitespace-separated word from `line`.

There would be better ways of writing that, we could e.g. remove the filename with shell expansions. This would output `23`:

```
line='23 somefilename'
res="${line%% *}"
echo "$res"
```

Or, just have `wc` not output the filename to begin with, by redirecting the file to `wc`'s stdin, instead of passing the filename to `wc`. Compare these two:

```
$ wc -c foo.txt
8 foo.txt
$ wc -c < foo.txt
8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i appreciate it. your explanation was very clear.. running the script in debug mode did show me the break but i did not realize what was really happening..

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for `wc -c`.

It outputs `bytecount filename` into `$line` as a space separated list.

The `for $woord in $line` loop reads the first variable (up till the first space) from `$list`, which is the `bytecount` and stores this in `$res`. Then instead of going on to read the next item in `$list` it hits the `break` instruction and exits the loop.

As @ikkachu says, there are easier ways to get the `bytecount`than with a loop.

Comment: thanks for your help.. i did read the man page.. in fact this little puzzle was bugging me for a while.. and i would never ask anyone for help if i did not put the effort of trying to understand and RTF it first.. even running the script with bash -x showed me what was happening but i did not fully comprehend what i was looking at.. thanks to all you guys i understand what's happening and why.